# Passing AngularJS $scope data to Jquery element (Stripe Checkout)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe Checkout which is built with Jquery into a SPA built with angular. I want to use the custom version and to be able to change data such as the amount or the email based on the current scope.

I have tried to write a directive:

```
.directive('ngSparkline', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      amount: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/stripe.html',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

Where stripe.html containsthe following snippet, as per Stripe's documentation:

```
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
      var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "pk_test_sK21onMmCuKNuoY7pbml8z3Q",
        image: "apple-touch-icon.png",
        token: function(token, args) {
          jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/stripetoken/", //For own custom domain, put the full https appspot url here
            data:  token,
            timeout: 200000,
            beforeSend: function(settings) {
              console.log("About to send the transaction, may take a while, but this will be async")
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
              alert("Paiement Effectué");
            },
            error: function(result) {
              console.log("Error",result);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("customButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
          name: "Vinify",
          description: "Recharge Vinibar",
          currency: "EUR",
          panelLabel: "Payer",
          amount: {{amount}}
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    </script>
```

but the checkout doesn't fire, even if I just try with a random amount hard written. When I put the same snippet directly in my html, replacing {{amount}} by a random amount, it works fine.

What would be the best approach? I want to use checkout because the UI is already built, and it would be a bit painful to rewrite it. I have tried angular-payments, but the code is messing with the ionic framework that I use.

Thanks!

Comment: I definitely would not place Angular bindings within `<script>` tags...

Comment: Yeah, it feels weird I know. But it worked for a simpler javascript snippet. Not with Jquery stuff though.

Comment: I think it would cause the browser to recompile and re-execute the entire contents of the `<script>` tag on each change of the bound value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put all the StripeCheckout stuff you have from this example in a link section of your ngSparkline  directive, and refer to it in the DOM like this:

```
<button ng-spark-line>Purchase</button>
```

In your link section, rather than using the element id to bind to click event, do this:

```
      $element.bind('click',function(e) {
        // Open Checkout with further options
        handler.open({
          name: "Vinify",
          description: "Recharge Vinibar",
          currency: "EUR",
          panelLabel: "Payer",
          amount: $scope.amount
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it would be the way, but never had to use the link function before. I declared the link function as: `link: function(scope, element, attrs)` so I used `element` and `scope` instead of `$element` and `$scope`. I saw it declared as such in various examples. Is this the right way?

Comment: There is no right way- I just prefer in my code to use the "$" to delineate that these are Angular objects